# Calculate total width of Children with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, layout

I've tried finding an understandable answer to this, but given up.

In order to have **dymnamic** content (like blog posts and images) in a **horizontal website** (like on [thehorizontalway.com](http://www.thehorizontalway.com/)) you must set a fixed width for the BODY in pixles, right? *Because you use floated elements inside it that otherwise would break and wrap down the page, depending on the browsers width.*

**EDIT!** This specific value can be *calculated* with **jQuery**, thanks for that :) In this example, an additional value is added to the total size, which can be used for content before the floated elements. Now the body gets a dynamic width!

My initial thought was to have jQuery calculate this for us:
( 'EACH POSTS WIDTH' * 'NUMBER OF POSTS' ) + 250 (for the extra content)

HTML code

```
<body style="width: ;"> <!-- Here we want a DYNAMIC value -->
<div id="container">
    <div id="menu"></div> <!-- Example of extra content before the floats -->
    <div class="post">Lorem</div>
    <div class="post">Lorem</div>
    <div class="post">Lorem</div> <!-- Floated elements that we want the sizes of -->
    <div class="post">Lorem</div>
</div>
...
<!-- So if these posts were 300px exept the last that was 500px wide, then the BODY WIDTH should be ( 300+300+300+500 ) + 250 [#menu] = 1650px -->
```

The result and answer from Alconja

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var width = 0;
$('.post').each(function() {
    width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
});
$('body').css('width', width + 250);
});
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Looks like you've got it pretty much right... a couple of notes though:

- `.outerWidth(true)` includes the padding & margin (since you're passing `true`), so there's no need to try & add that in again.
- `.outerWidth(...)` only returns the width of the first element, so if each element is a different size, multiplying this by the number of posts won't be an accurate value of total width.

With that in mind something like this should give you what you're after (keeping your 250 initial padding, which I assume is for menus & things?):

```
var width = 0;
$('.post').each(function() {
    width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
});
$('body').css('width', width + 250);
```

Does that help, or is there some other specific problem you're having (wasn't quite clear from your question)?

Comment: Awesome, that was just what I meant. I'll edit the question later so it's more clear what i was talking about. Like you said, the code I had only took the first .post and calculated the rest by multiplying them with .size() - this makes it so much easier to make a horizontal scrolling page, making the body's width dynamic per page :) Just needs some noscript super-body-width added and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the width with this one-liner, albeit a tad longer than I would have liked.

```
var width = $('.post').map(function(undefined, elem) {
    return $(elem).outerWidth(true);
}).toArray().reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev + curr;
}, 0);
```