# Slide gallery with image tooltips, images breaking out of unlimited width block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to develop a slide gallery with image tooltips according to this design:

[image: Design I am to implement]

What I need to develop is a slider controlled by two buttons, each time a button is pressed the slider's content must move a width of the slider or the width of the content left on that side, whichever is smaller. Upon mouse entering an image inside the slider the full-size version must be displayed as a tooltip.

[Here's a fiddle of my solution so far](http://jsfiddle.net/kotekzot/nE85N/), the problem I'm having is that images that don't fully fit into view plus the hidden area to the left get moved to a new line. You can see the problem by clicking the 
"Show content size" button, the width of the content element will be equal to the width of the container element + content element's margin-left.

Bonus points if you can suggest an algorithm for moving the content to the right, I've got left figured out to a T (or so I think, anyway), but right is going to take a little more work (it doesn't check whether the end of the content has been reached). **Update:** It seems I can't implement proper movement to the right until the other issue is resolved, here's the algorithm I came up with, I can't measure "left to display" if I can't measure the actual width of the content element.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created something you might like:

### *[gallery demo](http://jsbin.com/ozepod/6/)*

- The gallery does **not** scroll the *full gallery width* by default (you can change that) cause some initially cut-off images at the right side, after a 'full' slide would result cut-off again, just on the other side of our gallery. You have for that cause the `beKind` variable. Adjust it as you like.
- It hides the buttons if there's not enough content to make the gallery usable.
- The gallery calculates the remaining space to scroll.
- Once the slider end reached - the left/right buttons make the gallery jump to the beginning/end, so that are always usable. (Seems kinda weird to have a button... but that does nothing right? ;) )
- The **Tooltip** has a *hover-intent* built in, to not piss off our users if they unintentionally hovered our gallery: (the tooltip fades in if the hover is registered for more that 120ms. Fair timing. I like it.)
- **As pointed out in your comment** now the tooltip will not go off the screen.

### jQ:

```
// Slide Kind Gallery - by roXon // non plugin v. // CC 2012.
$(window).load(function(){  
    var galW = $('#gallery').outerWidth(true),
        beKind = 120, // px substracted to the full animation to allow some images to be fully visible - if initially partly visible.
        sumW = 0;       
    $('#slider img').each(function(){
        sumW += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    }); 
    $('#slider').width(sumW);
    if(sumW <= galW){ $('.gal_btn').remove(); } 
    function anim(dir){
        var sliderPos = Math.abs($('#slider').position().left),
            rem = dir ==='-=' ? rem = sumW-(sliderPos+galW) : rem = sliderPos,
            movePx = rem<=galW ? movePx = rem : movePx = galW-beKind;
        if( movePx <= 10){
            movePx = dir==='-=' ? movePx=rem : movePx = galW-sumW;
            dir = '';
        }
        $('#slider').stop(1).animate({left: dir+''+movePx },1000);
    }   
    $('.gal_btn').on('click', function(){
        var doit = $(this).hasClass('gal_left') ? anim('+=') : anim('-=');
    }); 
});
```

And the **tooltip** script:

```
// Addon // Tooltip script
var $tt = $('#tooltip');
var ttW2 = $tt.outerWidth(true)/2;
var winW = 0;
function getWW(){ winW = $(window).width(); }
getWW();
$(window).on('resize', getWW);
$('#slider img').on('mousemove',function(e){
    var m = {x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY};
    if( m.x <= ttW2 ){
       m.x = ttW2;
    }else if( m.x >= (winW-ttW2) ){
       m.x = winW-ttW2;
    }
    $tt.css({left: m.x-ttW2, top: m.y+10});
}).hover(function(){
    $clon = $(this).clone();
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        $tt.empty().append( $clon ).stop().fadeTo(300,1);
    },120);
    $(this).data('timeout', t); 
},function(){
    $tt.stop().fadeTo(300,0,function(){
        $(this).hide();  
    });
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
});
```

### HTML

(Place the `#tooltip` div after the `body` tag)

```
<div id="tooltip"></div>

<div id="gallery_container">
    <div id="gallery"> 
        <div id="slider">
            <img src="" alt="" />
            <img src="" alt="" />
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="gal_left gal_btn">&#9664;</div>
    <div class="gal_right gal_btn">&#9654;</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*GALLERY*/
#gallery_container{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:600px;
    padding:0 30px; /*for the buttons */
    background:#eee;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #888;
}
#gallery{
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    width:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#slider{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    height:100px;
}
#slider img{
    height:100.999%; /* fixes some MOZ image resize inconsistencies */
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-right:3px solid transparent; /* instead of margin that could leat to some wrong widths calculations. */
}
.gal_btn{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    width:30px; /*the container padding */
    height:40px;
    padding:30px 0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.gal_left{left:0px;}
.gal_right{right:0px;}
/* end GALLERY */

/* TOOLTIP ADDON */
#tooltip{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    width:300px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    box-shadow:0px 3px 6px -2px #111;
    display:none;
}
#tooltip *{
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
/* end TOOLTIP ADDON */
```

[Hope you'll like it](http://jsbin.com/ozepod/6/edit/), and you learned some useful *UI design* tricks.

By the way, if you want to populate your `ALT` attributes (Search engines like it!) you can also grab that text and make it appear inside the tooltip like here!:

### *[demo with text inside the tooltip](http://jsbin.com/ozepod/9/)*

Happy coding.

Comment: This is frigging awesome, thanks! Definitely going to give this a try.

Comment: Would be even better if the tooltips tried to stay within the window though.

Comment: @kotekzot Great catch! It was late and tired but now I added that in a minute. I even fixed a little tooltip issue : on mouseout a tooltip *ghost* was still there cause I was not `hide`ing it - resulting in not registering a new image-mouseover due to the presence of the *tooltip hidden element*.  **Reedited my answer**, take a look at the demo and the added lines of code under the jQ tooltip addon. Now we have a really impressive custom tooltip! :)

Comment: It's perfect! Is there a page for this plugin?

Comment: @kotekzot No, I created this for you (and for me cause I need something similar), but I will make one soon. Thanks to the power of jQuery it's quite easy to transform it into a plugin. Take a look at this: http://jsbin.com/ozepod/9/edit. Yet it's still a non-plugin code, it will not work with multiple galleries on one page.

Comment: Looking forward to the plugin, please shoot me a comment when you make it!

Comment: @kotekzot Will do my best. Will post here asap! (I even added the autoscroll! :) )

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand correctly your problem. If you set a width wide enough to .scroll-content div, images wouldn't go to the "next line". So a solution would be to set a width with css. If not, you could use jquery to determine the total width of all the images and give it to the .scroll-content div. [Calculate total width of Children with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015669/calculate-total-width-of-children-with-jquery)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. One caveat: if images aren't display: block, extra whitespace is going to throw the calculations off.

Comment: Could you show an example jsfiddle with the corrected width, please?

Comment: I've updated the fiddle with the correct code. http://jsfiddle.net/kotekzot/nE85N/