# CSS: how to set width to children's width?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a horizontal section, like `Quora.com`

[image]

Here is what I come up with

```
<div class="out-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <% 6.times do %>
      <a class="nav-link pull-left" href="#">Nav 1</a>
    <% end  %>
  </div>
</div>

.out-wrapper{
  overflow-x: scroll;
  .inner-wrapper{
    /* width: 600px; */
    .nav-link{
      padding: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJZyog**

I can only create a `horizontal scroll` if I set the `width` to a fixed value.

How can I do this without specify a fixed value? Like `width: overall-width-of-children`
So the width would automatically be the sum width of its all elements

Comment: Your css doesn't look to be valid. Maybe that's why it doesn't work?

Comment: show us demo page of what you tried sofar?

Comment: @Morpheus, See my update, I made a `codepen`

Comment: What is your question again? Do you want a scrollbar or do you want to distribute cells equally without scrollbar.

Comment: @SalmanA set the `width` automatically equal to the sum of children's `width`.

Comment: of course, If you set width and overflow-x as scroll, you ll get horizontal scroll only.. what else you need

Comment: @cqcn1991 is this what you want: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raJQgw ?

Comment: @SalmanA exactly, except it wouldn't consider for `float` element. I think I'll use your solution in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The browser will wrap elements into new line if they extend beyond the right edge so the width of the parent element will be 100% (max). To avoid this you have two solutions:

[**Use `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap`**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raJQgw)

```css
.out-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.out-wrapper .inner-wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.out-wrapper .inner-wrapper .nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2em; /* for demonstration */
}
```

```html
<div class="out-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav 1</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav 1</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav 1</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav 1</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav 1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Use `display: table` and `display: table-cell`**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogEQKP)

```css
.out-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.out-wrapper .inner-wrapper {
  display: table;
}
.out-wrapper .inner-wrapper .nav-link {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2em; /* for demonstration */
}
```

```html
<div class="out-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav 1</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav 1</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav 1</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav 1</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav 1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To succeed what you need, you have to add jQuery to your code to sum width of all your child elements. I have a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yfhmyv1m/) here of what you try to succeed.

HTML

```
<div class="out-wrapper">
   <div class="inner-wrapper">
     <% 6.times do %>
        <a class="nav-link pull-left" href="#">Nav 1</a>
     <% end  %>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.out-wrapper{
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;

}
.inner-wrapper{

}
.nav-link{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var container_width = 0;
    $('.inner-wrapper a').each(function() {
        container_width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
    });

    $(".inner-wrapper").css("width", container_width + 250);
)}
```

References:

[Make content horizontally scroll inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497373/make-content-horizontally-scroll-inside-a-div)

[Calculate total width of Children with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015669/calculate-total-width-of-children-with-jquery)

Comment: So there is no `css-only` way of doing it?

Comment: @cqcn1991 As i know, css is acting passive with html, and jquery is acting active. To sum children width it's an action, and an action it's done in an active way.