# jQuery calculate parent width from children

Tags: jquery, width, children, outerwidth

I'm trying to calculate the total width of a submenu relative to the children.
The following code only works fine in the first submenu, The second submenu needs a manual +1 in the width to make it work, else the last item will be pushed down.

```js
$('nav.primary').find('ul.sub-menu').each( function() {
    var width = 0;

    $(this).find('li').each( function() {
        width += $(this).outerWidth();
    });

    $(this).css({
        'width': width + 'px'
    });

    $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<li>
    <a href="/oplossingen/">
       Oplossingen<span class="fo icons-angle-down"></span>
    </a>
      
  <ul class="sub-menu">
 <li>
      <a href="/oplossingen/mvo-adviesdiensten/">
        MVO Adviesdiensten
      </a>
    </li>      
    <li>
      <a href="/oplossingen/co2-prestatieladder-advies/">
        CO2-Prestatieladder Advies
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

**The correct example:**

[image]

**The wrong example:**

[image]

**Width +1**
[image]

There isn't any other difference between odd and even items except the background color.

I've found the following similar question which couldn't solve my problem:
[Calculate total width of Children with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015669/calculate-total-width-of-children-with-jquery)

Comment: Also add your html code or create jsfiddle demo

Comment: Why not set the parent width to `auto` to adjust its `width` base on the content?

Comment: Don't forget to add type of measure: `$(this).css({ 'width': width + 'px' });`

Comment: @AlvinMagalona the submenu is positioned absolute so this won't work

Comment: @RonnyRook I said `html code` not screenshot

Comment: @Tushar Sorry man, I was a bit slow. Added it right now ;)

Comment: @kmsdev is this required?

Comment: @RonnyRook If you use `.css()` method, yes, you have to indicate the units. If you use `.width()` you can use only numbers (it understands pixels always).